# Sort files directory in array on c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, sorting, directory

[image]

I wan't to sort files directory.I have got a lot of file directions. Like:
`"C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\c11.txt"
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\a12.txt"
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\b11.txt"`

But it must sort by file names.
How can i do that?

```
Result i want:
a12 at top b11 in the middle c11 at last.
```

Here code sample.

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

fbd.ShowDialog();
kaynak = fbd.SelectedPath; 
dnm = Directory.GetFiles(kaynak,ftyp, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                .ToArray();
dsd = Directory.GetFiles(kaynak, ftyp, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Do you mean _"sort"_?

Comment: Sorry for that. sort is the right one.

Comment: You need to post the code you have.

Comment: You can use `Array.Sort` or Linq's `OrderBy`.  Can you share some code so we can determine what's most appropriate?

Comment: here there is a picture shows my file list. https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1AtE.png

Comment: @AhmetAliSoysal we need your _code_, not pictures.  Edit your question to include a [MCVE]

Comment: @Servy It might be a duplicate but that's the wrong source question. If you look at the image you will see that the OP have files from different paths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do it is using a labmda expression with `Array.Sort` (Please note I've changed the paths a little bit to show it's irrelevant to the sort:

```
var files = new string[]
{
    @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\c11.txt",
    @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\a12.txt",
    @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\ankara\b11.txt"
};


Array.Sort(files, (s1, s2) => Path.GetFileName(s1).CompareTo(Path.GetFileName(s2)));
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\a12.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\ankara\b11.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\c11.txt
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/JLCSOX17918)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solves my problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: @maccettura i am newbie here. I check green tic.Is that correct? Thanks..

Comment: Yes, you got it right

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Linq to sort by path:

```
var files = new List<string>
{
   @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\c11.txt",
   @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\a12.txt",
   @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\b11.txt"
};

files = files.OrderBy(f => f).ToList();
```

Result

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\a12.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\b11.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\programlama\destin\ankara\c11.txt
```

Comment: That would: 1) leave the original List of strings unsorted, 2) return an IEnumerable and 3) sort by the entire path.

Comment: Edited. I don't find it clear from the post if he wants to change the original list or not. Anyway, thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Better, but still needs to sort by file name only (and the original question was about an array, not a list, but that's just nitpicking :-))

Comment: @ZoharPeled Ouch! Totally misread the question. Good point. I'll give your answer an upvote. Thanks twice!

Comment: Don't worry about it, that happens to everyone... I'll bet even Jon Skeet have a deleted answer for that very reason :-)

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
filesArray.Select(q=> new { FullPath = q, FileName = Path.GetFileName(q)}).OrderBy(q=> q.FileName).Select(q=>q.FullPath);
```

Comment: I am not sure your code compiles.  You might want to fix the formatting and double check.

Comment: @maccettura I'm not sitting in front of my pc right now, i typed the solution from my head, but it should be ok if you import Sytem.Linq namespace.

Comment: It solves problem too. Thanks so much.

Comment: I would take a look again, specifically after your `Path.GetFileName(q)`...

Comment: I almost compiles, just replace the `;` with `,`. But it will not sort the original array, only return a sorted IEnumerable (and have poor performance, since it must iterate through the array 3 times).

Comment: @maccettura: topic starter can fine tune solution himself / herself, i only showed a possible solution, i' m on my smartphone with no pc and no compiler/debugger now, that's why the mistakes.

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki I understand, but answers with two words and code that does not compile aren't very _good_ answers.

Comment: I used to try and answer questions from my smartphone. Turns out not to be such a smartphone after all - it's really hard to do it right like this. My advise - don't do that. reading the question is hard enough, answering it correctly is even harder, especially when you have to include code in your answer.